# Insert a calculated row in a Tableau table

Tags: tableau-desktop

In the following Tableau dashboard, you can see that I have a table with 3 rows, ACO Partners, JOA, and Grand Total and then I have a bar chart that comes from this table on its right.

[image]

However, what I want to achieve is in the following screenshot.

[image]

I want to have all three rows as I have in the above Tableau table, however, I want to insert another row which is the percentage of the second row "JOA" and then use this newly created/ inserted row as the trend line on top of the bar chart.

How do you think that could be achieved with Tableau?

Comment: please provide some generic well prepared dataset in order to start from there with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image of chart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWOe5.png

To add measure value, You add: Measure values -> rows
2: You add line chart -> rows -> Right click in to value of chart -> dual Axis
3: Click on Analysis (File, Data, Worksheet..., Analysis) -> Stack marks -> OFF
```